# How can i create a object of public class BinarySearchTree<ContentType extends ComparableContent<ContentType>>

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, content-type

When i worked with Binary Trees i can create an object of this class like that:

```
BinaryTree<ContentType> b = new BinaryTree<>();
```

ConentType could be anything like int or String...

But with the class: `public class BinarySearchTree<ContentType extends ComparableContent<ContentType>>` i tried this:

```
BinarySearchTree<ComparableContent<int>> b = new BinarySearchTree<>();
```

but get the error Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType.

Any ideas how i create a binaryTree with a certain ContentType?

Comment: use `Integer` instead of `int`.

Comment: Then i get the error Bound mismatch: The type ComparableContent<Integer> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <ContentType extends ComparableContent<ContentType>> of the type BinarySearchTree<ContentType> instead.

Comment: `BinarySearchTree<? extends ComparableContent<Integer>>` !? Not sure what you are trying to do at the end of the day.